# When CDI speaks of a parameterized type, does it also incorrectly mean array types of parameterized element types?

Tags: java, cdi

CDI frequently [speaks of parameterized types](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0.html#assignable_parameters).

Does CDI (incorrectly) consider the array type `java.util.List<java.lang.String>[]` to be a parameterized type?  (It is [not](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5), of course; its [element type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1) is.)

I ask because there is a part of [the section on the assignability of non-generic classes, raw types and parameterized types](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0.html#assignable_parameters) that reads (with inline corrections of incorrect terminology usage, and the relevant parts **in bold**):

> A parameterized bean type is considered assignable to a parameterized required type if they have identical [?] raw type[s] and for each [of their corresponding] <s>parameter[s]</s>[type arguments]:
>
> - the required type <s>parameter</s>[type argument] and the bean type <s>parameter</s>[type argument] are [<s>actual</s>[non-variable reference] types](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/CDI-502?focusedId=13036118&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-13036118) [that are identical [?] [non-generic classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) or have]<s>with</s> identical [?] raw type[s], and, **if the type [?] is parameterized**, the bean type <s>parameter</s>[type argument] is assignable to the required type <s>parameter</s>[type argument] **according to these rules [recursively beginning with the section on (only partially-defined) [matching](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0.html#performing_typesafe_resolution)]**, or….

The **bold** bits are very important:

1. If "**if the type is parameterized**" is (correctly) *not* supposed to designate array types like `java.util.List<String>[]`, then at this point in the rules we would conclude incorrectly that, e.g., a bean type type argument of `java.util.List<Number>[]` could be assigned to a required type type argument of `java.util.List<String>[]`…

   1. …because the [only place where array type "matching" is discussed and handled](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0.html#performing_typesafe_resolution:%7E:text=The%20bean%20has%20a%20bean%20type%20that%20matches%20the%20required%20type.%20For%20this%20purpose%2C%20primitive%20types%20are%20considered%20to%20match%20their%20corresponding%20wrapper%20types%20in%20java.lang%20and%20array%20types%20are%20considered%20to%20match%20only%20if%20their%20element%20types%20are%20identical.) that would prevent this nonsensical state of affairs would never be "reached" (it's "reached" only when you apply the "**according to these rules**" step).
2. If it *is* supposed to (incorrectly) designate array types like `java.util.List<String>[]`, then (a) this is in conflict with the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5) and (b) means that other parts of [section 2.4.2.4](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/jakarta-cdi-spec-4.0.html#assignable_parameters) are somewhat redundant.

(My personal read is that in this one case only "parameterized type" *is* (erroneously) supposed to include array types with parameterized element types, but in no other case in this set of rules.)

(I think, if I've got this right, my rewrite of the clause in question would be something like: "…and, **if at least one of the two type arguments is either (a) a parameterized type, or (b) an array type with a parameterized element type**, the bean….".)

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may try the expert group mailing list. This is a good question, I'd love to know the answer too.